# What real-world projects would you suggest as code examples to study?

Tags: coding-style

What real-world projects would you suggest looking through the sources?

As I'm learning Java Swing, [mucommander](http://mucommander.com) seems to be a decent example. The code is excessively commented though.

EDIT: No shameless plugs plz :).

Comment: Are you only looking for Swing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Windows version of truecrypt. It is one of the best organized open source projects I've ever seen. You can almost tell how the whole thing works just from the directory and file layout.

Answer (score 2):

I learned a lot from looking at the source code to [GoGrinder](http://gogrinder.sourceforge.net/).  It's well thought out, uses MVC correctly, and the comments are helpful (and no, I didn't write it).  It's also a fun program to use if you want to learn how to play [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiqi).

Answer (score 1):

For Gui design, Patterns and general good advice I highly reccomend Jeremey Miller's series of articles on building a better CAB. For C#, but equally applicable to Java. Also using 
the MVC style which Stackoverflow follows, and Apple uses for Interface Builder.

[Build your own CAB](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/07/25/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents.aspx)

Jeremy's articles/ideas are followed in his own project, which you can download and inspect at http://storyteller.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to learn some new technologies over the years is to look to open source projects that both match the criteria you're looking for and also interest you.

I'm not a Swing guy, but I'd suggest finding a project that uses Java Swing, does not appear too complicated, and then start digging through the source.  The nice thing is you can then see the app before you start poking through it, and then you can see what happens as you change stuff.

The idea behind picking something that interests you is that it will keep you engaged.  I am intrigued by content management systems, so I might download a CMS that I can then see how stuff works, and I'm engaged because the problem domain of the project fits in with an interest.

I've done this once or twice when I had to get up to speed on C# and I think it works will.  YMMV....

Answer (score 0):

Some of the most well thought out source code ( c++ ) I have seen in an open source project is the Ogre3D graphics engine, I've learned a lot about OOA&D just by looking at the structure and reading the comments. It is also well maintained and the community is very active.. http://ogre3d.org